# Storing data in a side table that may change in its main table

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, database-design

This is an overall question of best practice when designing a database and I have been unable to correctly word my question to find an answer on the net.

I have a database that is holding information about employee's safety training. The information about requirements needs to be stored for auditing purposes, but year to year the requirements may change. I still need to keep a record of what an employee was required to do and how much of it they completed.

My first reaction was to create a table for historical data and store basically a "snapshot" every time an employee completes an action or the time required to complete the action expires, that way if the requirement changes years down the road the historical table won't be pointing at the wrong information.

I altered this upon implementation and have set up the application so that it doesn't change existing requirements it creates a new one every time the requirements change so that the old requirement is still in the database and pointed to by the historical table. On the main table the requirement table the old requirement is marked as inactive and can never be deleted through the application.

I am sure this problem has been encountered before but I have been unable to articulate it well enough to search viable answers on my own. My question is what is the best way to proceed in this situation? Is my current implementation a good one? Was my first reaction better? Is there another way that is better than both?

On a side note if there is a word or phrase for this type of problem (the storing of redundant data, storing historical data, storing auditing data, I'm not sure what to call it) please let me know.

Comment: Back compatibility, perhaps? Or versioning?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand you have an employee and associated tasks. I would create one table for employees and one for the tasks. Another many to many table will link these to. In the task table you will have a status and date effective from/to columns. if the task is currently effective you can leave the effective to date null or set the value to 1/1/2999. When querying the tasks you will need to provide a date so you will be able to get the task effective as of a specific date. If you decide to use null value the where clause will be  like

where t.DateEffectiveFrm<=@AsOfDate and (@AsOfDate < t.DateEffetiveTo or t.DateEffetiveTo is null)

if for currently effective tasks you use a date value in the far future ( 1/1/2999) the where clause will be even simple
where t.DateEffectiveFrm<=@AsOfDate and @AsOfDate < t.DateEffetiveTo

You might consider also to add a status table , which will keep a history of the status changes