# Tables with data that will never be deleted or changed

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server, database, database-design

This is a more in depth follow up to a question I asked yesterday about storing historical data ( [Storing data in a side table that may change in its main table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18770900/storing-data-in-a-side-table-that-may-change-in-its-main-table) ) and I'm trying to narrow down my question.

If you have a table that represents a data object at the application level and need that table for historical purposes is it considered bad practice to set it up to where the information can't be deleted. Basically I have a table representing safety requirements for a worker and I want to make it so that these requirements can never be deleted or changed. So if a change needs to made a new record is created.

Is this not a good idea? What are the best practice to deal with data like this? I have a table with historical safety training data and it points to the table with requirement data (as well as some other key tables) so I can't let the requirements be changed or the historical table will be pointing to the wrong information.

Answer (score 2):

> Is this not a good idea?

Your scenario sounds perfectly valid to me.  If you have historical data that you *need* to keep there are various ways to meeting that requirement.

**Option 1**:

Store all historical data and current data in one table (make sure you store a creation date so you know what's old and what's new).  When you need to retrieve the most recent record for someone, just base it on the most recent date that exists in the table.

**Option 2**:

Store all historical data in a separate table and keep current data in another.  This might be beneficial if you're working with millions of records so you don't degrade performance of any applications built on top of it.  Either at the time of creating a new record or through some nightly job you can move old data into the other table to keep your current table lightweight.

Comment: I think Option 2 is close to what I need, but I'm having trouble wrapping my head around what needs to be done with the foreign keys and constraints. To clarify the problem a bit more, I have a table for employees, a table for requirements, a table for actions. Action gets assigned to requirement, requirement gets assigned to employee, employee completes action. So I need an additional table for all 3 is what you're saying?

Comment: I guess it depends on what you want to do.  Replicating the other tables (employee and action) just for historical purposes seems redundant (unless you have historical details for those as well, but, it sounds like you don't).  I would just keep a history of the requirements and forgo the foreign key enforcement for the historical data.  You can always join it to the other tables (if you need to correlate data for some reason) even if you don't have proper foreign key enforcement.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one alternative, that is not necessarily "better" but is something to keep in mind...

You could have separate "active" and "historical" tables, then create a **trigger** so whenever a row in the active table is modified or deleted, the old row values are copied to the historical table, together with the timestamp.

This way, the application can work with the active table in a natural way, while the accurate history of changes is automatically generated in the historical table. And since this works at the DBMS level, you'll be more resistant to application bugs.

---

Of course, things can get much messier if you need to maintain a history of the whole graph of objects (i.e. several tables linked via FOREIGN KEYs). Probably the simplest option is to simply forgo referential integrity for historical tables and just keep it for active tables.

If that's not enough for your project's needs, you'll have to somehow represent a "snapshot" of the whole graph at the moment of change. One way to do it is to treat the connections as versioned objects too. Alternatively, you could just copy all the connections with each version of the endpoint object. Either case will complicate your logic significantly.